# decoding haskell pcap header

Tags: haskell, pcap

I am trying to get more information out of [`PktHdr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pcap-0.4.5.2/docs/Network-Pcap.html#t:PktHdr) in the 
[pcap](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pcap) Haskell library.

But it seems like the type does not give me much. How can I get things like source address, destination address and port? Do I have to translate the bytes myself, or am I not reading the doc for this library correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That library looks as if it's a Haskell version of the libpcap/WinPcap library for C/C++, which means it does nothing more (other than "being callable from Haskell) tha libpcap/WinPcap does.

I.e., it does absolutely *no* dissection of the packet data; you're on your own there.  It just hands you raw packet data.

So, yes, you have to analyze the packet bytes yourself, just as you would with a C/C++ program using libpcap/WinPcap.

Some quick Web searching for

```
"haskell" packet analysis
```

found [Etherbunny](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Etherbunny), which is described as "Currently not very useful, but getting there."  It was uploaded almost 8 years ago, and the home page link is broken, and I couldn't find anything more recent, but, hey, it's a start, and it *does* appear to include code to parse Ethernet, IPv4, and TCP headers.